# laravel routes in production server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.4

Dear stack overflow community,

I am working on Laravel framework and I was able to put it on production sever

Everything worked fine, till I tried the Laravel authentication module

I tested forgot password function and it worked.
The issue is with the reset password link that Laravel sent to email

Instead of domain_name/password/reset/

I get

domain_name/App_URL/password/reset/

Which causes

> not found page error message

My question is why the reset link appends the APP_URL, it's already the domain name

Please, your help is appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you haven't pointed the domain to the /public directory or set up a symlink between that and public_html

Comment: @AndyHolmes hi andy, i did changed the httpd.conf file in server to point to my/project/pat/public and all routes in project are working fine except for the reset link, can you explain more the symlink?

Comment: did you check the APP_URL in your .env file? maybe a typo

Comment: @CUGreen my APP_URL is the same as the server name, it basically generate reset link: APP_URL/APP_URL/password/reset/<token>

Comment: Ah sorry I misread, check the routes in the files produced to see if theres an accidental addition